# Append multiple values for a key from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I've got a file similar to below:

```
t_air_sens1
laten
t_air_sens1
periodic
t_air_air
laten
t_air_air
periodic
...
...
```

I want to make a dictionary in order to assign those values of *laten* and *periodic* to each key of *t_air_sens1* and etc. The final result must be something like below:

```
{
    "t_air_sens1": [laten,periodic]
    "t_air_air": [laten,periodic]
     ...
     ...
}
```

I did write the code below:

```
prop_dict = {}
with open('file.pl') as f, open('result.pl', 'w') as procode:
     for line in f:
         if line[0] in prop_dict:
            prop_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
         else:
            prop_dict[line[0]] = [line[1]]
         #will write the values in "result.pl"
```

But the result I get when I try to print the dictionary is something like below:

```
{'p': ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'],
 't': ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_',
       '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
 'l': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']}
```

What can I do to fix it? How do I need to make queries in order to get the proper result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line[0]` and `line[1]` are single characters in the string, not the current line and the next.

File objects are iterators; the `for` loop will get new lines from it each iteration, but you can also use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to pull another line in. Use this to read two lines at a time:

```
prop_dict = {} 
with open('file.pl') as f:
     for key in f:
         key = key.rstrip('\n')
         # get the next line as the value
         value = next(f).rstrip('\n')
         prop_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

I also used [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to insert an empty list for any key that is missing from the dictionary. Like `prop_dict[key]`, it'll return the current value in the dictionary, but if there is no such key, `prop_dict[key] = []` is executed first before returning that empty list.

How the above works is that the `for` loop reads lines one by one as the loop iterates, basically by using `next()` internally. Calling `next(f)` in the loop simply draws in an extra line, and the `for` loop continues from there again, so you are alternating between reading a property name (`key`), and a property value (`value`).

Note that `next()` can raise a `StopIteration` exception if the end of the file was reached by reading the last line in the `for` loop; this would indicate your file did not have an even number of lines. If this is not an error, you could specify a default instead: `next(f, '')` would return the empty string `''` if the file has been exhausted.